# A dimension question related to the restriction to a finite-codimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space, $T:V \to V$ a linear operator and $W \subset V$ a subspace with $\operatorname{codim} W < \infty$. If $\dim \operatorname{Coker}(T) < \infty$, do we necessarily also have $\dim \operatorname{Coker}(T\vert_W) < \infty$?

Intuitively, $\operatorname{Coker}(T\vert_W)$ is larger than $\operatorname{Coker}(T)$, but not much larger, since $W$ is rather "large" inside $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the exact sequence of vector spaces

$$ V/W \xrightarrow{T} V/T(W) \xrightarrow{\mathit{Id}} V/T(V) \to 0,$$

so $\dim V/T(W) \leq \dim V/W + \dim V/T(V),$ and both are finite by hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes let $V=W\oplus U$ for some finite dimensional space $U$.
We have a decomposition
$$V=im T_W + im T_U + Q$$ for some finite dimensional $Q$. 
Clearly $im T_U + Q$ is finite dimensional and bounds the dimension of the 
cokernal of $T_W$

Comment: Thanks. How do we arrive at the decomposition $V = imT_W + imT_U + Q$?